# Tomcat container fails to use <error-page> configuration if exception occurs after the response object's OutputStream is opened

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, containers

I'm using Tomcat 5.5 and Spring 3.2. In the web.xml deployment descriptor, I have the following configuration -

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

The unexplained behavior occurs in a method similar to the one below -

```
public ModelAndView fileDownload(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                 HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
 {
    String filename = (String) request.getParameter("filename");  
    //...more code
    File file = new File(...+ filename); // pseudo code
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file); // FileNotFoundException here
    //...more code
 }
```

When a FileNotFoundException occurs, I don't see my custom 500.jsp used to render the error page, but instead I see the entire stack trace of the exception on the page. If I simply reverse the order of the two statements as below,

```
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file); // FileNotFoundException here
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```

everything works correctly and I get the correct 500.jsp rendered on the page.

Why does this occur? The only difference was that in the latter case, the OutputStream of the response object was not opened.

Comment: just test it with Tomcat 5.5.36 + Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE and can't get any problem as you describe here. Custom `500.jsp` page rendered always as expected. And no dependency on sequence of these two lines of code. Please provide more configuration files to reproduce this error.

Comment: can you provide the stack trace you see on the page?

Comment: @CodeBlue if you are still looking for an answer, please provide the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, the JSP is likely attempting to call the getWriter method on the HttpServletResponse. According to the spec, getWriter can be called or getOutputStream can be called, but not both. Since you have already called getOutputStream, the JSP is unable to write to the response.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/182025

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an `IllegalStateException`? The OP seems to imply that the `FileNotFoundException` is thrown and displayed on the error page, but without more information it's hard to tell. If the exception displayed on the error page _is_ the `IllegalStateException`, then I suspect this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add custom controller to render pages defined in `web.xml`.

@see description here: [Custom error pages in Tomcat with Spring](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/04/how-to-custom-error-pages-in-tomcat.html)

Comment: This is already working for dozens of pages without the custom controller stuff.

Comment: I just create test case and don't reproduce your problem, but I don't have Tomcat 5.5. I'm use Tomcat 7 + Spring 3.2. Result is not dependent on this two lines sequence. Maybe problem with web.xml or with jsp error pages?

Answer (score -1):

It is only a guess, but I think the problem is related to the point, that you can not change http response (header) after is is send to the client. Or more precise: See [Benjamin Pack´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980025/tomcat-container-fails-to-use-error-page-configuration-if-exception-occurs-aft/18029474#18029474)